# Number partitions of n into less than k terms equals partitions of any number with none more than k

Tags: combinatorics, integer-partitions

Pretty much want to show that the number partitions of n into no more than k terms equals the number partitions of n into any number of terms, each one not exceeding k.

I was given the hint that you can use reflections in y=-x of a Youngs diagram to show this. And I think that means you can create a 1 to 1 correspondence between the 2 partitions by swapping the rows and columns of the diagram to get the other one. But I don't really see how you can then use that to show the statement to be true.

Comment: If there are less than $k$ terms in the first partition, there are less than $k$ elements in each set in the second, and v.v. Just look at what rows and columns mean in the diagram.

Comment: Example  12 = 4 + 3 + 3 + 1 + 1  --> 12 = 5 + 3 + 3 + 1 found as follows: 5 =(# terms), then subtract one from each term giving 3 + 2 + 2; i.e. 3 terms, reduce to 2 + 1 + 1; i.e. 3 terms reduce to 1 i.e. 1 term. This process is equivalent to what you described without drawing the diagram. It's clear that the number of terms in the one partition equals the max term in the other; also, the inverse of this operation is itself (i.e. it's an involution).